# Define a dictionary as string

Tags: ansible

I would like to run a task in Ansible like this:

```yaml
- name: Task
  set_fact:
    var: >-
      {"system": [{
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"}]}
```

The variable `var` is considered as a dict by Ansible but I want it to be a string to template it in a config file. Any suggestion ?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think it becomes a dict ? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70585961/edit) your question with the debugging step you have taken and the reasoning behind that conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

You're mistaken. The value of the variable is not a dictionary. It's a string. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _var: >-
          {"system": [{
           "key1": "value1",
           "key2": "value2"}]}
    - debug:
        var: _var
    - debug:
        var: _var|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: _var.system.0.key1
```

You can see that the type is *AnsibleUnicode* and the path in the dictionary is undefined

```yaml
  _var:
    system:
    - key1: value1
      key2: value2

  _var|type_debug: AnsibleUnicode

  _var.system.0.key1: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

---

You can convert the string to the dictionary

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: _var|from_yaml
    - debug:
        var: _var|from_yaml|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: (_var|from_yaml).system.0.key1
```

You can see that the type is *dict* and the path in the dictionary is defined

```yaml
  _var|from_yaml:
    system:
    - key1: value1
      key2: value2

  _var|from_yaml|type_debug: dict

  (_var|from_yaml).system.0.key1: value1
```

Comment: In reality, I did this which become a dic.

```
- name: Task
  set_fact:
    var: >-
      {"system": [{
      "key1": "{{ templa1 }}",
      "key2": "{{ template2 }}"}]}
```
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is [a feature or a bug](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/4BES7nRDoCQ).